# Import / create a weighted and undirected graph from a txt file in igraph

Tags: python, igraph, weighted

I want to make a weighted and un-directed graph in python.

I have an edge list in a text file (all_edges.txt) in which each line shows 2 letters and a number

the first and the second letters are the nodes that are connected to each other and the number is the weight of the corresponding edge. for example:

```
A  B  5
```

This means that node A is connected to node B and the weight of the corresponding edge is 5.

Here is the code that I've written to import the graph from the text file:

```
from igraph import *
import csv as csvlib
import random
import numpy as np

graph = Graph.Read_Ncol('all_edges.txt', weighted=True, directed=False)
```

but I don't know how to include the weight of the edges.

Comment: Nice question. see my answer

Answer (score 0):

**Assuming** that you have a `.txt` file like this:

```
A B 2
B C 3
```

---

**Use `Graph.Read_Ncol` and `directed=False` as follows:**

```
g = Graph.Read_Ncol("edges.txt",names=True, directed=False)
```

---

**Verify using:**

```
print(g.get_edgelist())
print(g.es["weight"])
print(g.vs["name"])
```

**Results:**

```
[(0, 1), (1, 2)]
[2.0, 3.0]
['A', 'B', 'C']
```